# PHP substr used with preg_replace

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

I have function:

```
function postNumberToLink($string) {
 return preg_replace('!\>\>\d+!', "<a href='#$0'><font color='red'>$0</font></a>", $string);
}
```

My questions:

- What's better (generally): Formatting string before putting it to db, or formatting clear text after querying it from database?
- I'd like to change every element compatibile with pattern ($0) in function above which means to remove first two characters (>>) and put the rest into href. I was trying to use substr on it, but it crashed. I also read about preg_replace_callback where I did put function as a second parameter and it also crashed even when I write inside the function the simpliest code. How can I make text like

`"I'm replying to post no. >>21313123"` to `"I'm replying to post no. [href=21313123][red]>>21313123[/red][/href]"` ?

Sorry for brackets[], but I can't figure out how do SO tags work.

Regards
Matt

Comment: Always store the unprocessed text. That way if you want to allow editing then you'll be able to without having to "un-parse" it.

Comment: More than just editing, "formatting" implies a target medium (in this case, formatting *as HTML*). If you want to feed the data to more than one target medium the only sane choice is to keep it unformatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your Questions

1. Keep it in your syntax in the database. This has several advantages:

   - You are not limited to HTML only. What if you make an API tomorrow that outputs JSON or XML?
   - You don't need to unparse and reparse it every time you need to edit.
2. You can use control groups in your regular expression:

   ```
   return preg_replace('!\>\>(\d+)!', "<a href='#$1'><font color='red'>$0</font></a>", $string);
   //                        ^   ^ Brackets!     ^^ First group        ^^ All match
   ```

### Extra Points:

- Don't use `<font>` it's deprecated since before Jon Skeet had less than 100k reputation. Instead, use a `class` name on your links, and use CSS to style those:

  ```
  <a href="#" class="reply-to">
  ```

Comment: thanks a lot bro! You made a mistake with a proper order of vars - first should be $1, and the second one $0, but that's ok now i fully understand.

I really appreciate this!